# How can i convert string timestamp into date fromat in android?

Tags: android, datetime

Explanation:
           I have a timestamp in string format which comes from the server in json file.my timestamp is like 1454544000 this format. I stored this time into String variable.

Here is my code

```
Timestamp ts=new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date d=new Date(ts.getTime());
Log.e("TimeStamp",""+d.toString());
```

but it returns current today's date. I want to convert my timestamp which i got from json file.

How can i convert above timestamp into date fromat????

Comment: Please give a specific example of an input value with an expected output value.  "date format" is too vague.

Answer (score 2):

The code should look like this:

```
long timestamp = 1454544000;
Date date = new Date(timestamp);
```

If ever you wanted also to have a customized format of your date, you can try to using `SimpleDateFormat`. Here's a sample code as well:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
```

For further info about `SimpleDateFormat`, you can check this one out: [Simple Date Format](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: it returns Sun Jan 18 05:24:50 GMT+05:30 1970 like that

Comment: why it's returns year in 1970

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
import java.util.Date;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        //Since you mentioned that you have timestamp in string format, so I have taken timestamp as string and parsed it to long in Date()
        String timestamp = "1454544000" ; //Example -> in ms
        Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(timestamp));
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

So you can use these two lines in your Android app:

```
String timestamp = "1454544000" ; //Example -> in ms
Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong(timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

store the time in long from json instead of string and pass it in below code :

```
String time = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, 1454544000, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));
String date =  DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, 1454544000, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE));
```

Comment: it return same January 18, 1970

Comment: The above returns incorrect answers because the DateUtils works on seconds (UNIX) but value being passed are ms,


Multiply the value by 1000 and you will get the correct Date.

Answer (score 0):

Store your timestamp in a long type variable named TimeinMilliSeccond and then

```
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(TimeinMilliSeccond));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Use below method for Convert JsonDate to normal format.


public static String ConvertJsonDate(String jsondate) {

    jsondate = jsondate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
    long time = Long.parseLong(jsondate);
    Date d = new Date(time);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy").format(d).toString();
   }

    //Now you use this method this way
    String date1 = ConvertJsonDate("Yourjsondate"); //give argument like 1454544000 
    System.out.println(date1);
```